# So I'm trying to make a quiz but if I can't change the value of score because I set it as zero in the function but putting outside has an error

Tags: python, syntax-error

```
    import time

global score
score = 0
```

The score above doesn't work inside or outside the functions.

```
donea = False
doneb = False

def restart():
    print('Do you want to restart?')
    restartyn = input().lower()
    if restartyn == 'yes' :
        main()
    else :
        print('Ok goodbye.')
        time.sleep(2)
        quit()
def main():
    print('Hello welcome to my quiz!')
    time.sleep(1)
    print('Would you like subject A, B or C?')
    subject = input().lower()
    if subject == 'a' :
        print('Your choice was \'Maths\'')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('So what is 5 * 70?')
        Aanswer = int(input())
        if Aanswer == 350 :
            score += score
```

When I try to add to the score it has an error saying it was referenced before assignment even though I assigned it above outside the function.

```
            print('Well done your score is now ' + str(score) + '!')
            donea = True
            restart()
        else :
            print('Sorry that is the wrong answer')
            time.sleep(2)
            restart()
    elif subject == 'b' :
        print('Your choice was \'science\'')
        time.sleep(1)
        print('What is the symbol for the element \'gold\'?')
        Banswer = input().lower()
        if Banswer == 'au' :
            score += score
            print('Well done your score is now ' + str(score) + '!')
            doneb = True
            restart()
        else :
            print('Sorry that is the wrong answer.')
            time.sleep(2)
            restart()
main()
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify inside your `main()` function that the variable `score` you are using is the global one. As it is, score is a newly created local variable

```py
def main():
    global score
```

Try adding this line to your function.